# How connect variables of different classes with mutliple dependency injection?

Tags: python, class, dependency-injection, dependencies

I'm trying to make dependency injection to connect two classes together.
For instance with the below code:

```
class one():
    def __init__(self,two):
        self.b = 0
        self.C_two = two

    def compute(self):
        print(self.a)
        self.b = self.b + 1

    @property
    def a(self):
        return self.C_two.a


class two():
    def __init__(self,one):
        self.a = 0
        self.C_one = one

    def compute(self):
        self.a = self.a + 1

    @property
    def b(self):
        return self.C_one.b

class three():
    def __init__(self):
        self.C_one = one()
        self.C_two = two(self.C_one)
        self.b = 0

    def compute(self):
        self.C_one.compute()
        print('C_one a=',self.C_one.a )
        print('C_two a=',self.C_two.a )

C_three = three()
for i in range(5):
    C_three.compute()
```

class `one()` has the property 'a' of class `two()` and class `two()` has the property `b` of class `one()`. But obviously I get an error from the line `self.C_one = one()` in class `three()` because I don't know `self.C_two` yet. How can I create reciprocal link between two classes like in my example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if `one` needs a `two` and `two` needs a `one` then your only solution is to use a two-stages initialisation of either `one` or `two`:

```
class three():
    def __init__(self):
        self.C_one = one(None)
        self.C_two = two(self.C_one)
        self.C_one.two = self.C_two
```

but it's still a probable design smell...

Comment: Ok, I will use that then. Thanks